# How to change the TDateEdit dropdown calendar size on Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Does anybody know how I could change the dropdown calendsr's width? As you can see, from localization, the string for the month doesn't really fit, plus I'd like the calendar to be the same size as the combo (TDateEdit).

[image]

Comment: Which version of Delphi and what style are you using?

Comment: Using XE 10.2 (Tokyo) and the style is a "fork" of Copper style.

Comment: Do you see a change for the better, if you try with any of the standard styles, like `Air.Style`? When I try in `XE7`, with just a `TDateEdit` and a `TStyleBook` I can't see the problems you describe.

Comment: Indeed, other styles don't seem to have the spacing problem and all text is displayed... so looks like that's a font/size problem in that style (plus if it wasn't localized, I'm sure "December" would have fit - but localized in Romanian it has one extra character). But still, any way to change the width of the calendar to fit the combo?

Comment: Doubleclick the stylebook so the style editor opens. Look in the object tree for `calenderstyle: TLayout` and select it. Then in the properties window scroll down to `width` and edit. Finally select `Apply and Close` or if that is missing, click the `X` to close the style editor window, which will ask you to keep or discard the edits you made.

Comment: What I said in my previous comment works in XE7, but not in 10.1 Berlin. Sorry, but I can't investigate further now.